# Combining duplicate a lot of entries with unique data in Excel

Tags: excel, merge

I have duplicate entries like this and I want to do this like attached image:

[image]

How can I do that?

I've got these data in the Excel sheet:

```
ID   Name   Groups
1    John      A
1    John      B
2    Lora      A
2    Lora      A
3    Matthew   C
4    Andrew    A
4    Andrew    H
1    John      C
```

I want to merge duplicate data to this:

```
ID     Name    Groups
1      John    A,B,C
2      Lora    A
3      Matthew C
4      Andrew  A,H
```

Then, I created another column called "Test", to combine Groups, if ids are equals(the same) and groups are distintcs:

`SI( Y(A1=A2;C1<>C2) ; D1&", "&C2 ; C2 )` (This form is for spanish excel, I don't know how the functions is called in English) and it does not work.

I think in English the form is: `IF( AND(A1=A2;C1<>C2) ; D1&", "&C2 ; C2 )`

Comment: You linked to a stackoverflow post which apperently answers your question. What exactly do you want someone to do here? Explain your question in more detail, and tell us what part of the linked answer is confusing to you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we will be happy to help you debug your code.  Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: If you search SO for `[excel] combine duplicate rows` you will find a number of examples which could easily be adapted to your problem

Comment: Hello, i edited again my post. Sorry for the inconvenients!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the formula as :-

=IF(A2=A1,C1&","&B2,B2)

And so on as described in the post you have shared.

Comment: I use this form: =SI( Y(A1=A2;C1<>C2) ; D1&", "&C2 ; C2 ) and it doesn´t work

Comment: Try using the form mentioned above. Your form is incorrect.

Comment: I edited again the main post, to avoid confussions. Sorry!